# why is 'Brackets' sidebar not working in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: adobe-brackets

**Problem 1 :** I installed Ubuntu 18.10, after successful installation, i tried to install Brackets (version 1.13) using Terminal .
I used command to install 'Brackets' from terminal is...

```
gdebi Brackets.Release.1.13.64-bit.deb
```

but output throws an error...

> Reading package lists... Done 
>    Building dependency tree 
>   Reading state information... Done 
>    Reading state
>   information... Done 
>    This package is uninstallable Dependency
>   is not satisfiable: libcurl3

I used above command in **previous versions** of 'Ubuntu' and it installed without any error .

**Problem 2 :** After **problem 1** i tried to install Brackets from "Ubuntu's software center" and i installed successful .
But when i open it, the **sidebar of Brackets** is not working .
when i opened a folder through *'Brackets'* in which all my program files are present then i saw that the 'sidebar' doesn't display any files .

What is wrong here....

Answer (score 1):

> gdebi Brackets.Release.1.13.64-bit.deb

Probably a version that is too old or too new since `Dependency is not satisfiable: libcurl3` means it can not install a mandatory piece of software for this to work.

I would have issued a ...

```
sudo apt install libcurl3
```

and see if that installs and then act upon the error or install brackets again if it does not throw an error. gdebi likely does not install dependencies so you will need to do that yourself.

> After problem 1 i tried to install Brackets from "Ubuntu's software center" and i installed successful .

That would be my 1st choice (over gdebi installation).

> then i saw that the 'sidebar' doesn't display any files .

That we probably can not help you with. That seems related to the software itself. It could be a bug in Brackets.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! after run "`sudo apt install libcurl3`" in terminal then it throws an output with error **E: Package 'libcurl3' has no installation candidate**

Comment: due to this, i'm going to install **Deepin** and remove 18.10

Comment: That does not guarantee you do not face the same issue ;)

Comment: i have installed **Deepin** and **Brackets** is working fine .